# Calling function to return className

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What I'm trying to do is call a function that will return a className based on what the val is equal to but I'm getting an error on the call function or maybe its the way I return the classNames. Can someone show me a proper way to do this? I think the mistake is in the way checker() is being called.

```
const checker = val => {
  if (val === "A")
    return "typeA"
  else if (val === "B")
    return "typeB"
  else 
    return "typeC"
}

const Button = props => {
    <div className={checker(props.children)}>{props.children}</div>
}
```

Comment: what is the error you're getting ? ***hint:*** check what `console.log(props.children)` looks like ?

Comment: You cannot edit HTML elements through Javascript the way you have attempted to do it. See here - https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_html.asp

Comment: @Rojo - ever used reactjs

Comment: @JaromandaX nope... Oops, didn't note the reactjs tag

Comment: @Rojo - the concept of the code in the question is valid, perhaps the implementation isn't

Comment: @Rojo - by the way, links to w3schools are often met with derision - not sure why, w3schools is good for absolute beginners, then after an hour, it should be never used again :p

Comment: @JaromandaX Oh, I've always used that or Mozilla Developer. I find w3schools easily accessible though.

Comment: @Code Maniac I get a lot of errors trying to console.log(props.children), but props.children is mainly for the styling that I have based on className in a separate css file I have.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are missing a `return` statement:

```
const Button = props => {
  return (<div className={checker(props.children)}>{props.children}</div>);
}
```

you can shorten it a bit though:

```
const Button = props => (
  <div className={checker(props.children)}>{props.children}</div>
);
```

Notice I have changed your `{` and `}` to `(` and `)`.

Other parts in your code should work.

```
<Button>A</Button>
```

will render `<div class="typeA">A</div>`

Comment: Haha ya I was just about to edit my post and it seems I in fact WAS missing a return statement. Thank you though!